# Plot an non-linear function with poles

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a non-linear function with poles but I can not get the results. The code I am using is

```
H = np.diag((1, 2, 3, 4))
g = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])

Lambda, U = np.linalg.eig(H)
psi = lambda l: np.linalg.norm(np.dot(np.diag(1. / (np.diag(Lambda + l))) @ U, g))**2
x = np.arange(-16.0, 4.0, 0.05)
y = [psi(xx) for xx in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The expected result is

[image]

Could you please someone suggest a way to handle the poles and get the result?

Comment: Instead of `plt.plot(x, y)` try `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); ax.plot(x, y); ax.set_ylim((0, 25))`.

Comment: Or simply add `plt.ylim(-1, 20)`. But the object-oriented method hilbert suggested is the preferred approach.